# How can I strip the time from the result of applying DatePlus?

Tags: output-formatting, date-and-time

`DatePlus["12 May 2017",2]`

gives

`"Sun 14 May 2017 00:00:00"`

How can I get just the `"14 May 2017"`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It gives a `DateObject` as a result, not a string. What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: I mean how can I get "14 May 2017" from the result. I want to compare it with another date.

Comment: Do you want a string?   If so, use `DateString` on the `DateObject` (please look it up in the documentation).

Comment: You left off the `"` marks, and I did not understand your question at all.  I fixed it.  What do you mean by "compare"?  Please try to clarify your question.  Do you want  to decide which date is earlier? Do you want to format the date as a string?

Comment: Is there an issue with `StringDrop[#,-9]&@DatePlus["12 May 2017",2]`?

Answer (score 2):

One can just set the value of `$DateStringFormat` locally within a `Block[]`, like so:

```
Block[{$DateStringFormat = Riffle[{"Day", "MonthNameShort", "Year"}, " "]},
      DatePlus["12 May 2017", 2]]
   "14 May 2017"

Block[{$DateStringFormat = Riffle[{"Day", "MonthNameShort", "Year"}, " "]},
      DatePlus["12 May 2017", 42]]
   "23 Jun 2017"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = DatePlus["12 May 2017", 2];

DateList[d][[;; 3]]
```

> {2017, 5, 14}

Or

```
DateObject @ DateList[d][[;; 3]]
```

[image]

Comment: How is that `"14 May 2017"`? I mean, OP asked for a string.

Answer (score 1):

For explicit control over output, you may want to look at `DateValue`;
e.g.

```
DateValue[DatePlus["12 May 2017", 2], {"Year", "Month", "Day"}]
```

> {2017, 5, 14}

If you want month-name explicitly (but trickier possibly for comparisons):

```
DateValue[DatePlus["12 May 2017", 2], {"Year", "MonthName", "Day"}]
```

> {2017, "May", 14}

---

If you're going to handle date comparisons (subtraction, let's say), you may want to leave it in `DateObject` form, then convert; e.g.

```
DateObject @ DatePlus["17 May 2032", 15] - 
DateObject @ DatePlus["12 May 2017", 2]
```

> Quantity[5497, "Days"]

---

If you really want a string "for comparison" (string compare??), as Szabolcs commented, you can read about `DateString` [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html):

```
DateString[DatePlus["12 May 2017", 2], 
 Riffle[{"Year", "MonthName", "Day"}, " "]]
```

> "2017 May 14"

If you're going to be manipulating `DateObject`'s anyway, `DateString` will inherit whatever format you give the `DateObject`:

```
DateString[
 DateObject[DatePlus["12 May 2017", 2], 
  DateFormat -> Riffle[{"Year", "MonthName", "Day"}, " "]]]
```

> "2017 May 14"

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing date calculations/comparisons it would be better to work with [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) than to work with string representations of dates. With strings you miss out on the many built-in features for handling dates; see *Date Operations* and *Tests on Dates* in the [Date and Time](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DateAndTime.html).

#### Convert to `DateObject`

To explicitly convert a date string you would use `DateObject`'s string syntax, extract the [`DateValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateValue.html)s and then feed that back into `DateObject` for a `"Day"` granularity date. It is a bit verbose to be explicit so create a pure function with this steps.

```
toDateObjectDay = 
 DateObject[
   DateValue[DateObject[{#, {"Day", "MonthName", "Year"}}], {"Year", "Month", "Day"}], 
   "Day"] &;
```

String dates of this form can be converted to `"Day"` `DateObject`s.

```
dt = toDateObjectDay@"12 May 2017"
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that this date has `"Day"` granularity and no time components since they were note chosen with `DateValue`.

#### Date Operations & Comparisons

All date operations will preserve the date granularity.

```
DatePlus[dt, 2]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Even if the operation involves a lower granularity.

```
DatePlus[dt, {1, "Hour"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `DateObject`s also allows you to use comparison operators.

```
stringDates = {"3 June 2014", "12 May 2017", "30 Sep 2017", "1 March 2022"};
dates = toDateObjectDay /@ stringDates
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Select[# <= dt &]@dates
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Select[Between[{Today, DatePlus[Today, {2, "Decade"}]}]]@dates
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Formatted Strings

`DateObject`s can be converted back to formatted strings with [`DateString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html).

```
DateString[dt, Riffle[{"Day", "MonthNameShort", "Year"}, " "]]
```

> ```
> "12 May 2017"
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which version do you use? With *Mathematica* 11.2.0 `DateObject[{"12 May 2017", {"Day", "MonthName", "Year"}}]` returns the `DateObject::str: String 12 May 2017 cannot be interpreted as a date.` error, while simple `DateObject["12 May 2017"]` returns the expected output.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes, version 11.2.0 and I don't have 11.1.1 installed at the moment but I think this works in 11.1 as well. Last time `DateObject` was updated was in 11.1

Comment: I mean `toDateObjectDay@"12 May 2017"` returns a bunch of errors...

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov All the code above works in 11.2

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Windows 7 x64: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECYAE.png).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Seems to work on WIndows 8.1 Pro - [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g7G2R.png)